# django security and user control

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, django-admin

**how to prevent  people from editing post and publishing and approving and deleting post of other people who are logined in the system in django.i am creating a forum where anyone can post question.i need help to control users who are already registered in the system**
**this my post_deatil.html**
    {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="post">
       {% if post.published_date %}
    <div class="date">
        {{ post.published_date }}
    </div>
{% else %}
    {% if id.is_authenticated %}
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">Publish</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'post_remove' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'post_edit'  pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
<hr>
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk %}">Add comment</a>
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated or comment.approved_comment %}
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="date">
            {{ comment.created_date }}
            {% if not comment.approved_comment %}
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'comment_remove' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'comment_approve' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
                <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>

            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>
        <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% empty %}
    <p>No comments here yet:</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**this my view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post, Comment
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .forms import PostForm, CommentForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    """posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).get_latest_by('published_date')"""
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
@login_required
def post_new(request):
    form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
@login_required
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
@login_required
def post_draft_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=True).order_by('created_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_draft_list.html', {'posts': posts})
@login_required
def post_publish(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.publish()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=pk)
@login_required
def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()
@login_required
def post_remove(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.delete()
    return redirect('post_list')
@login_required
def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})
@login_required
def comment_approve(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comment.approve()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)

@login_required
def comment_remove(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    post_pk = comment.post.pk
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=post_pk)
```

Comment: i have used this and still other people who are login  can edit other person post and they are not suppose since they are only suppose to edit their post only.`{% if id.is_authenticated %}` i have used that and it not working at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can control it just by checking is authenticated user of session a author of entry.

Comment: how  can i control that what i am asking because i tried in this line and its not working at all    `{% if id.is_authenticated %}
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">Publish</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'post_remove' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'post_edit'  pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    {% endif %}`